# Dagger 2 injection in Fragments and swapping Modules

Tags: android, dagger-2

I've started using Dagger 2 and I'm not sure if I'm doing things right as I ran in the following complication:

Let's say I have a `HouseModule` initialized with a `House` and a `WindowModule` initialized with a `Window`.

Now I have a `HouseFragment` which is supposed to general Information about the house.
Thus I created a `HouseComponent` including the `HouseModule`.

So far so good.
Now there are multiple nested `HouseDetailsFragment`s within the `HouseFragment`(ViewPager) which show information about the `House` and the `Window`.
I created a `HouseDetailsComponent` including the `HouseModule` and the `WindowModule`.

My dependency graph looks like this:

```
// provides application wide dependencies (Application context, SharedPref, Repository,...)
@Component(modules = {ApplicationModule.class}) 
public interface ApplicationComponent { 

}

// provides general activity dependencies (Navigator,... )
@Component(dependencies = ApplicationComponent, modules = {ActivityComponent.class}) 
public interface ActivityComponent{
    void inject(MainActivity mainActivity); 
}

// provides house fragment specific dependencies (HousePresenter,...)
@Component(dependencies = ApplicationComponent, modules = {ActivityComponent.class, HouseComponent.class}) 
public interface HouseComponent extends ActivityComponent {
    void inject(HouseFragment fragment);  
}

// provides house details fragment specific dependencies (HouseDetailsPresenter,...)
@Component(dependencies = ApplicationComponent, modules = {ActivityComponent.class, HouseComponent.class, WindowComponent.class}) 
public interface HouseDetailsComponent extends ActivityComponent {
     void inject(HouseDetailsFragment detailsFragment);  
}
```

Component creation becomes increasingly complex this way and I wonder how to inject dependencies to the `HouseFragment` and especially the `HouseDetailsFragment`s best.
e.g. to build the `HouseDetailsComponent` I have to do the following:

```
// casting omitted
DaggerHouseDetailsComponent.builder()
.applicationComponent(getActivity().getApplication().getApplicationComponent())
.activityModule(getActivity().getActivityModule())
.houseModule(getParentFragment().getHouseModule())
.windowModule(new WindowModule(window)).build().inject(this);
```

I dislike the knowledge (and casting) required about parent fragments and activities.
Is there a simpler way to achieve what I want to do? Any other suggestions about the dependency graph?

Also how do I show a different `House` in the `HouseFragment`? i figured creating a new `HouseModule` and then swapping the other out... but how do I do that? There are no accessors afaik.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been using submodules to simplify the hierarchy.

Also [Dagger 2.11+ supports Android](https://google.github.io/dagger/android.html) and makes injections for it easier.